# Как работать с сайтом в се TOR onion HTTPS:// HTTP/2

Tags: https, tor, http2, onion

Друзья, всем доброго дня.
Проблема в следующем, пишу код для парсинга сайтов и все работает отлично, но тут столкнулся с сайтом работающем на https:// и запросы принимает по http/2 протоколу, и если с тор браузера работает нормально то когда я пытаюсь на него попасть с кода с рабочими куками, то ничего не выходит

```
import asyncio
from httpx import AsyncClient
from httpx_socks import AsyncProxyTransport
async def fetch(url):
    headers = {
        "Cookie": "PHPSESSID=9BCE8121B7D021D20D3A47AE6544BC2A; instance=A1; service=2b42a1864dac37f07c348c8dcdb2ee1f; captcha_uid=ba207581-e3cf-4190-b8ae-96a717f3bfe6",
        "Host": "... .onion",
        "Referer": "https://... .onion",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/115.0",
    }
    print(headers)
    transport = AsyncProxyTransport.from_url(f'SOCKS5://127.0.0.1:9050')
    async with AsyncClient(http2=True, transport=transport) as client:
        res = await client.get(url=url, headers=headers)
        print(res.http_version, res.status_code)
        print(res.headers)
        return res.text
async def main():
    text = await fetch('https://... .onion')
    print(text)
asyncio.run(main())
```

httpx умеет работать с http2 протоколом, а вот через тор может ли она работать? Готов отблагодарить за помощь в решении проблемы

пробовал разные библиотеки (aiohttp, httpx) , но ...